# Weimaraner puppy eating poo

Tags: dogs, behavior, defecation

We have a 11 week old Weimaraner puppy who has been eating his poo at night. We are coming downstairs to let him out to do his business, but sometimes he has already done this and just the remains after left. Any advice to stop this before it becomes an engrained behaviour?